# Using a specific ruby version : RVM and bundler

Tags: ruby, rvm

i'm a newbie on using RVM and bundler so i face off an issue after install my bundle.
I created a gemfile like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

#ruby-gemset=starter-d6-susy

#ruby=ruby-1.9.3-p484 

gem "compass", "0.12.2"
gem "sass", "3.2.12"
gem "susy", "1.0.9"
gem "modular-scale", "1.0.6"
gem "compass-recipes", "0.3.0"
gem "zocial", "0.0.3"
```

and the bundle install do:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Installing chunky_png 1.3.3
Installing fssm 0.2.10
Installing sass 3.2.12
Installing compass 0.12.2
Installing compass-normalize 1.5
Installing compass-recipes 0.3.0
Installing sassy-math 1.5.1
Installing modular-scale 1.0.6
Installing susy 1.0.9
Installing zocial 0.0.3
Using bundler 1.7.11
Your bundle is complete!
```

then when i want to compile my scss to css with compass, i get :

```
compass watch /var/www/drupal6/sites/all/themes/d6_pf_susy/
LoadError on line ["36"] of /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb: cannot load such file -- susy
```

this is because the system doesn't use 1.9.3 but 1.9.1 as i understand..but i've set the right ruby version:

```
 rvm use
Using /home/webmaster/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484
```

what can i do to fix this ? why do i get an error if i put 1.9.3 without dash ?

```
Gemfile syntax error on line 9: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot
ruby=ruby-1.9.3-p484
              ^
on line 9: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER
ruby=ruby-1.9.3-p484
               ^
```

thanks

Comment: Add `bundle exec` before each command

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify Ruby version as follows in Gemfile:

```
ruby '1.9.3'
```

Also try:

```
gem uninstall sass
gem install sass
```

**Note**: You should ideally be using a version of Ruby greater than 2.1.0 by now.

Comment: can i use : ruby '1.9.3-p484' ? without = sign ? does ruby 2.1.0 will affect usage of older versions of sass or compass ?

Comment: after modifying : still error : compass watch /var/www/drupal6/sites/all/themes/d6_pf_susy/
LoadError on line ["55"] of /home/webmaster/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- susy

Comment: Can you try to reinstall sass? `gem uninstall sass` and `gem install sass`?

Comment: the issue come from susy : if i do `gem list` , susy is not in the list, but if i do `bundle install` , susy is in the list..o_O

Comment: ok seem to fix it with install of susy gem then reinstall the bundle..no error message on `compass watch`..hope it will be for long time

Comment: Okay, have updated the answer; please mark answer if it fixed your issue.